# ValueError: Can not squeeze dim[1], expected a dimension of 1, got 3 for '{{node ctc/Squeeze}} with input shapes: [?,3]

Tags: python, keras

I'm trying to implement CTC alignment for my video sequence labelling task with the Keras lambda function. All available sample codes are for speech/text alignment. I'm not sure where the lambda function can be used as such for Videos. When I tried, I'm getting the error:

> ValueError: Can not squeeze dim[1], expected a dimension of 1, got 3
> for '{{node ctc/Squeeze}} = SqueezeT=DT_FLOAT,
> squeeze_dims=[-1]' with input shapes: [?,3]

```
def ctc_lambda_func(args):
    y_pred, labels, input_length, label_length = args
    # the 2 is critical here since the first couple outputs of the RNN
    # tend to be garbage:
    # print "y_pred_shape: ", y_pred.shape
    y_pred = y_pred[:, 2:, :]
    # print "y_pred_shape: ", y_pred.shape
    return K.ctc_batch_cost(labels, y_pred, input_length, label_length)
labels = Input(name='the_labels', shape=[None], dtype=dtype)       # transcription data (batch_size * y_seq_size)
input_length = Input(name='input_length', shape=X_train_length.shape, dtype=dtype)  # unpadded len of all x_sequences in batch
label_length = Input(name='label_length', shape=label_length.shape, dtype=dtype)  # unpadded len of all y_sequences in batch
y_train=np.ndarray(shape=(num_files,max_y_length),
                     dtype=np.float32)
y_train.fill(1)

# Lambda layer with ctc_loss function due to Keras not supporting CTC layers
loss_out = Lambda(function=ctc_lambda_func, name='ctc', output_shape=(208,30))([y_pred,  y_train,  X_train_length, label_length])
```